# Does it makes sense to prune filters in convolutional layer when rank of filters is smaller than number of filters?

Tags: conv-neural-network, matrix, matrix-decomposition

Let’s consider a convolutional layer, taking filters (matrices used in convolution), vectorizing them, putting them into matrix $A$ and computing it's rank. Does it makes sense to remove $|filters|-rank(A)$ filters from this layer (these that has $0$ or low singular value)?